# Django rest framework serializer is valid always false

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

I have problem with Django. I did all as was written in the tutorial but when I check is_valid on serializer there is always false.

Here is my code:

```
models.py
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'email')
```

And then I run `python manage.py shell`. Then I use commands like:

```
from belmondoapp.models import User
from belmondoapp.serializers import UserSerializer

u = User(userId="user", email="asd@gmail.com")
s = UserSerializer(data=u)
s.is_valid()
```

And it always returns False... Why? What did I wrong?

Comment: Check `s.errors` after calling `s.is_valid()`

Comment: By the way, I think that the problem is that your `u` does not have an ID (which is required by your serializer). You should save it first

Comment: I got ``{'non_field_errors': ['Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got User.']}`` by calling s.errors

Comment: When I use ``u.save()`` then it is added to User and then I pass it to the serializer like UserSerializer(u) and now s.data is visible, but when I put UserSerialize(data=u) and then s.is_valid() there is false... Maybe its becouse the user with the same id exists?

Answer (score 26):

After having the same problem I'd like to highlight the solution offered by @Andrea Corbellini in the comments section:

```
print(s.errors)
```

Will return a dictionary containing the `fields: reason for fail`.  In my case this looked like:

```
{
'start_date': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a date but got a datetime.', code='datetime')],
'end_date': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a date but got a datetime.', code='datetime')],
'client': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Client.', code='incorrect_type')]
}
```

I found this absolutely invaluable.

Comment: Super helpful. Found my error using this. It was with format on one of the DateField. In case anyone is reading, add `input_formats=['insert some date format here']` in your serializer DateField params

Comment: Awesome answer! I had the same error and it turns out that one of my fields was required and I was passing nothing.

Answer (score 8):

```
s = UserSerializer(data=u)
```

should be:

```
s = UserSerializer(data={"userId"="user", "email"="asd@gmail.com"})
```

The serialization process (from the Model to the dictionary) doesn't require a call to `is_valid`:

```
s = UserSerializer(instance=u)
s.data
```

The deserialization process (from dict to Model) doesn't accept Model:

```
s = UserSerializer(data={"userId"="user", "email"="asd@gmail.com"})
s.is_valid()
s.validated_data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see exception details use `raise_exception` argument as `True` i.e

`obj.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`